# Needing Help on a Loop for averaging grades using awk. Output prints the same grade for every student

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, awk

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS = "\t" 
    OFMT = "%.2f"
    }

$4~/[0-9]/ {

    EARN[$1$2]+=$4
    POS[$1$2]+=$5
    CLASS[$1]++
    TYPE[$2]++
}
END{ 
    TOTAL=0
    for (STUDENT in CLASS){ 

        HW=(EARN[$1"Homework"]/POS[$1"Homework"])*0.30
        LAB=(EARN[$1"Lab"]/POS[$1"Lab"])*0.50
        QUIZ=(EARN[$1"Quiz"]/POS[$1"Quiz"])*0.10
        FINAL=(EARN[$1"Final"]/POS[$1"Final"])*0.10
        WS=(EARN[$1"Survey"]/POS[$1"Survey"])*0.10
        TOTAL=(HW+LAB+QUIZ+FINAL+WS)*100
        GRADE= "A"

        if (TOTAL < 90) {
            GRADE="B"
        }
        if ( TOTAL < 80){
            GRADE="C"
        }
        if (TOTAL < 70){
            GRADE="D"
        }
        if( TOTAL < 60) {
            GRADE="E"
        }

    }
    print "Student\t Total \t Letter Grade"
        print STUDENT, TOTAL, "\t" GRADE    
}
```

The code /should/ give a unique grade for every student, but with my sample file every student receives the same grade (which i assume is the first student's grade), The code is going through column 4 EARN (earned points) and comparing it to column $5 POS (possible points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 primary problems with your script (but good job and good effort -- you were close). The first is you need to move your print statements. The first to the beginning of `END`, e.g.

```
END{ 
    print "Student\t Total \t Letter Grade"
```

And the next within the `for (STUDENT in CLASS){` loop, e.g.

```
        if( TOTAL < 60) {
            GRADE="E"
        }

        print STUDENT, TOTAL, "\t" GRADE    
    }
}
```

The second and most problematic error is the use of `$1` in, e,g, `HW=(EARN[$1"Homework"]/...` instead of using `STUDENT` (which is your loop variable), e.g. `HW=(EARN[STUDENT"Homework"]/...`

Along with the second, in your calculations, if a student does not have a specific grade (like `"Survey"` or `"Final"` as in the data you supplied in the comment), the you will receive a divide by zero as there will be no corresponding, e.g. `POS[STUDENT"Survey"]` and it will be taken as zero.

You can avoid that with a ternary to make sure the elements is nonzero or use `1` for the value, e.g. Instead of:

```
    FINAL=(EARN[STUDENT"Final"]/POS[STUDENT"Final"])*0.10
```

you can use:

```
    FINAL=(EARN[STUDENT"Final"]/(POS[STUDENT"Final"] ? POS[STUDENT"Final"] : 1))*0.10
```

(this just ensures the denominator is `1` if the index isn't in the `POS` array)

With that change you can use:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS = "\t" 
    OFMT = "%.2f"
}

$4~/[0-9]/ {

    EARN[$1$2]+=$4
    POS[$1$2]+=$5
    CLASS[$1]++
    TYPE[$2]++
}
END{ 
    print "Student\t Total \t Letter Grade"
    TOTAL=0
    for (STUDENT in CLASS){ 

        HW=(EARN[STUDENT"Homework"]/(POS[STUDENT"Homework"] ? POS[STUDENT"Homework"] : 1))*0.30
        LAB=(EARN[STUDENT"Lab"]/(POS[STUDENT"Lab"] ? POS[STUDENT"Lab"] : 1))*0.50
        QUIZ=(EARN[STUDENT"Quiz"]/(POS[STUDENT"Quiz"] ? POS[STUDENT"Quiz"] : 1))*0.10
        FINAL=(EARN[STUDENT"Final"]/(POS[STUDENT"Final"] ? POS[STUDENT"Final"] : 1))*0.10
        WS=(EARN[STUDENT"Survey"]/(POS[STUDENT"Survey"] ? POS[STUDENT"Survey"] : 1))*0.10
        TOTAL=(HW+LAB+QUIZ+FINAL+WS)*100
        GRADE= "A"

        if (TOTAL < 90) {
            GRADE="B"
        }
        if ( TOTAL < 80){
            GRADE="C"
        }
        if (TOTAL < 70){
            GRADE="D"
        }
        if( TOTAL < 60) {
            GRADE="E"
        }

        print STUDENT, TOTAL, "\t" GRADE    
    }
}
```

(**note:** I would use `"F"` as the final grade instead of `"E"` -- never heard of that one..., and also use *lower-case* names for your user variables)

**Example Use/Output**

Based on the data you provided you would receive:

```
$ ./calcgrades.awk grades.txt
Student  Total   Letter Grade
Chelsey 86.89           B
Sam     40.77           E
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Wow thank you, I appreciate you helping me with this! I apologize for the terrible formatting of the data. I was stuck on it for the better part of the last few days.

Comment: It was a forest for the trees issue -- one you could look at for days and not snap to the fact that you should use `STUDENT` instead of `$1` (happens to us all) -- welcome to programming and scripting `:)`